# Why is Hawking's No Boundary condition described in terms of an instanton if there's no tunneling?

Tags: cosmology, universe, cosmological-inflation, quantum-tunneling, fine-tuning

Regarding his take about combining No Boundary proposal with inflation theory (Hawking and Turok), he talks about the "pea instanton".

To my very limited understanding I thought instantons were only for describing quantum tunneling phenomena. The No Boundary proposal doesn't subscribe to this, it just says that the Euclideanized 4-spatial-dimensioned pre-Planck-era universe was always there and there was no t=0?

Or does it actually involve a tunneling process like Vilenkin's?

Comment: I wish I knew enough to answer this... if I can find anyone who knows about such things I'll point them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analogously to the use of SU(2) instantons for describing tunelling between topologically distinct vacuum sectors, I've [heard](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.1479) people talk about gravitational instantons as describing a tunneling process connecting "nothing" with an expanding Minkowski signature universe.  People talk heuristically of a universe having emerged by tunnelling from "nothing".

> When it comes to cosmology, one must be cautious with the word
>   “tunneling” since it now refers to the “birth of a cosmos from
>   nothing”. What’s more, the relevant path-integral now involves a sum
>   over 4-geometries, which seems much farther from mathematical (or even
>   physical) respectability than what we were considering earlier. Still,
>   if we are willing to neglect a number of important complications, we
>   can make the problem seem remarkably close to more homely examples of
>   tunneling, like the one treated above. This of course, is basically the
>   view people have taken in discussing “creation of the universe via a
>   gravitational instanton”.

Comment: This is correct, but it does make it weird to use an _instanton_, since there is no non-imaginary time version. This is a very strange idea, probably the wierdest Hawking ever had.